# what is the plist key for "Prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari.plist?

Tags: safari, plist

I need to disable Prevent cross-site tracking option in Safari by using command line.

As I explored Safari options can be changed via plist changes as below

defaults write com.apple.safari SendDoNotTrackHTTPHeader -boolean true

I just want to know what is the key value for the option "Prevent cross-site tracking"

Answer (score 1):

defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist BlockStoragePolicy 1

1 is disabled
2 is enabled

Terminal needs full disk access